# How to fix 'Could not find method defaults()'?

Tags: gradle

I use gradle version 5.2.1. I have the following gradle.build:

```
jar {
    baseName = 'test-jar'
    version = '0.0.1'
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
                'Implementation-Title': project.name,
                'Implementation-Version': project.version
        )
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'https://company.jfrog.io/repo'

    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'maven-repo'
            username = ''
            password = ''
        }
    }
    defaults {
        publications('mavenJava')
    }
}
artifactoryPublish {
    dependsOn jar
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

and when I try run artifactoryPublish I get this exception:

> Could not find method defaults() for arguments
>   [build_9u5pvo7mijp1ik3gd8paa2ytp$_run_closure4$_closure10@21e4a36] on
>   root project 'TestProject' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Please help me to solve this issue. 
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Try to run `gradle` with `--debug --stacktrace` parameters to get more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking [the doc](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin#GradleArtifactoryPlugin-UsingtheArtifactoryPluginDSL), the `defaults` method should be inside the `publish` method at the same level of `repository` block

```
artifactory {
      //....
      publish {
            repository {
                repoKey = 'maven-repo'
                username = ''
                password = ''
            }
            defaults {
               publications('mavenJava')
            }
      }
}
```